# How to add new values to a new column in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to do some computations with the data stored in a dataframe. ANd put the result into new column of this dataframe.

Initial dataframe:

```
    > str(mydf)
    'data.frame':   1122 obs. of  6 variables:
     $ MMSI       : num  2.73e+08 2.73e+08 2.73e+08 2.73e+08 2.73e+08 ...
     $ MMSI.1     : num  2.73e+08 2.72e+08 2.72e+08 2.72e+08 6.67e+08 ...
     $ LATITUDE   : num  46.9 46.9 46.9 46.9 46.9 ...
     $ LONGITUDE  : num  32 32 32 32 32 ...
     $ LATITUDE.1 : num  46.9 46.9 46.9 46.9 46.9 ...
     $ LONGITUDE.1: num  32 32 32 32 32 ...
```

Now I need to add a new column which contain the result of operation with the data of the current raw..

running next code:

```
    library(geosphere)
     > mydf$distance <- with(mydf, distGeo(c(mydf$LONGITUDE,mydf$LATITUDE),c(mydf$LONGITUDE,mydf$LATITUDE)))
    Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1) : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2
```

I understand that's the structure of the data for function distGeo should be different. 
How to fix this error or how to change the code to get the distances between point in a new column?

Comment: Please `dput` a part of the data

Comment: There is no need to include `mydf$` before each column name as you have referenced the dataframe by using `with`.  There also appears to be an error that you are calculating the distance between a single point.

Comment: thanks for your comment about using 'with' operator. The error is not that i am calculating the distance between a single point.

Answer (score 1):

Without having data to look at, it looks like you are trying to calculate the distance between a single point.  The second point should likely include `.1` at the end of the column name

```
library(geosphere)
mydf$distance <- with(mydf, distGeo(c(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE), c(LONGITUDE.1, LATITUDE.1)))
```

**update**

It looks like the error is that you're passing the entire data frame instead of each row individually.  Try this

```
apply(mydf, 1, function(x) distGeo(x[c("LONGITUDE","LATITUDE")],x[c("LONGITUDE.1","LATITUDE.1")]))
```

Or just pass specific data columns to function as it accepts a matrix

```
distGeo(mydf[,c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE")], mydf[,c("LONGITUDE.1", "LATITUDE.1")])
```

Comment: No, the problem is not here.. The problem is that the data required for the distGeo must be in another format... But i don't get how to change it.

Comment: p1, p2 parameters: longitude/latitude  of  point(s).   Can  be  a  vector  of  two  numbers,  a  matrix  of 2 columns (first column is longitude, second column is latitude) or a Spatial-Points* object

Comment: @twistfire added example using `apply` to pass vectors by each row and how to filter the `data.frame` to pass the values as a matrix.